# int32 is not convertible to int

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a random number generator ios app in xcode and I'm getting an error while trying to use the rand() method I get the following error; "int32 is not convertible to int" I've tried to change "int" to "int32" and it gave me no errors but since I did that no numbers are displayed. How do I get around this problem?

Note: I'm using swift language

Code:

```
@IBOutlet var lblNum: UILabel!
@IBAction func btnGenerateNum(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let text: Int = rand()

    switch(text) {
    case 0:
    lblNum.text = "0"
    break;

    case 1:
        lblNum.text = "1"
        break;

    case 2:
        lblNum.text = "2"
        break;

    case 3:
        lblNum.text = "3"
        break;

    case 4:
        lblNum.text = "4"
        break;

    case 5:
        lblNum.text = "5"
        break;

    case 6:
        lblNum.text = "6"
        break;

    case 7:
        lblNum.text = "7"
        break;

    case 8:
        lblNum.text = "8"
        break;

    case 9:
        lblNum.text = "9"
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func btnGenerateNum(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {

    lblNum.text = "\(arc4random_uniform(10))"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize an Int with your Int32:

```
let text: Int = Int(rand())
```

Comment: @Justin You should technically post that issue as a separate question, but I'll answer anyway. It is in fact randomizing (print it to see), but it can return numbers up to 10 digits or so long...so way bigger than the number 9 in your final switch case.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be easier for you? (Not necessarily a solution to the random number generator issue that you raised)

```
let text = String((Int(rand())) % 10)
lblNum.text = text
```